# How to display a 12 hour timestamp in chronological order on a slicer? (POWERBI)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

The desired slicer I am trying to achieve is to get the slicer to list out the time in hour chronologically (e.g 12am-11am and then 12pm - 11pm)

[image]

This is how my dataset looks like.
What I have tried to do is sort my datetime column in ascending order first. Which will sort my 12H clock conversion column into the desired format and then use the sort by column function to format my 12hour timestamp by the 12hour clock conversion column. However my slicer turned out looking like this.

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sort by column method is correct. However using the 12HClock Conversion column as reference to sort the time is wrong as it is also in 12-hour format thus leading to the wrong slicer output.

Instead the hour column can be used as it is in ascending order from 0-23 which would format your time in a chronological order.